# What is the correct way to use multi-part schematic symbols in Altium designer?

Tags: altium

I have a library containing FPGA schematic symbol and related footprints. It has become clear to me that the scheamtic symbol is not unified but split into multiple parts. These parts represent different banks of the FPGA and the power supply pins.

When I drag and drop the schematic symbol from library, I always get Bank 1. It is not clear how to get the other banks. I tried to use copy paste but that also does not work.

Also, if by mistake I end up having two Bank 1 for the same component, how will it get detected later on? It is not clear to me how Altium designer will do the annotation part where it assigns the part numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Part ID parameter in the part's properties is what you're looking for.

Note to check "Lock Part ID" so it doesn't try and update your parts during annotation (if you use it)!

SHIFT+Drag copying the part always gives the next in sequence, a handy way to place them.  Placing from library also gives them in sequence.

Repeat parts with identical designators throw a "duplicate" error on compile and show a red squiggly underline on the schematic.

Comment: Shift and drage, so that is what I was missing. I see.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the part of the symbol from properties:

[image]

Comment: Alright, so it must be done from here. What if we have duplicates, i.e we went up with two Part A by mistake. At what stage will Altium capture it? I mean how does Altium know if all the Part A, B, C ... e.t.c. belong to single component or different components?

Comment: In my example above, they are all parts of U1